# How can I remove empty columns in comma-separated values?

Tags: perl

I have a variable. Example:

```
date= 56788,45677,56908,34462,,41278,68977,55532
```

After the value `34462` there are two commas, how can I remove the extra comma there, using Perl.

Comment: That is not a Perl variable, and in general not really Perl code. Instead of trying to invent fake code, ask about your actual problem and show your real code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use substitution to replace two commas by a single one:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $date = '56788,45677,56908,34462,,41278,68977,55532';
$date =~ s/,,/,/g;
print $date;
```